# IP switching from static to DHCP (WMI) doesn´t work

Tags: dhcp

I switch my LAN-Connection between static and DHCP by code (WMI).
But there must be something wrong with the code. Because if I switch back from static to dhcp, the LAN-Connection get a new IP and subnet, but they are wrong and the next problem is, the gateway is still the static one from before.
I checked them with "ipconfig /all". I use my app with admin-rights, so this is not the problem.
If I check the LAN-Connection in the windows control panel, after I switched back to DHCP, the hooks are all right.
I´ve tried "ipconfig /renew" and "ipconfig /release" too, but nothing helps.

Why doesn´t it work? What is wrong in my code? There is no error in Visual-Studio.

If I switch from static to DHCP manualy (open control panel and set the hooks by my self), then the DHCP works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got the problem.
It is necessary to deactivate and activate the LAN-Connection, after switching to DHCP.